# Android WebRTC DataChannel is always null and ICE candidates are not sent

Tags: java, android, kotlin, websocket, webrtc

I'm trying to create an Android app that uses WebRTC data channels for data exchange. The data that I want to send is basic strings. Admittedly, this is my first time looking at WebRTC, and so I am a bit fuzzy on the details. My problem is that whenever I try to create a data channel, it is always null, and ICE candidate requests do not seem to be exchanged with the signalling server. I started from [this example that creates a connection to exchange video between two devices](https://github.com/amrfarid140/webrtc-android-codelab) and modified it to not exchange video but instead create a data channel.

I looked through a lot of other answers but the vast majority have to do with WebRTC in the browser, and data channel examples are rare to begin with. I also looked through the google chromium source code implementation of WebRTC in c++ to see if anything could be learned but had no luck.

My code is as follows

**WebRtcActivity.kt**

```kotlin
// imports omitted
class WebRtcActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var rtcClient: RTCClient
    private lateinit var signallingClient: SignallingClient

    private val sdpObserver = object : AppSdpObserver() {
        override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {
            super.onCreateSuccess(p0)
            signallingClient.send(p0)
            println("session description to string: " + p0.toString()) // prints
        }
    }

    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_rtc)

        // camera permission check omitted
        onCameraPermissionGranted()
        
    }

    private fun onCameraPermissionGranted() {
        rtcClient = RTCClient(
                application,
                object : PeerConnectionObserver() {
                    override fun onIceCandidate(p0: IceCandidate?) {
                        super.onIceCandidate(p0)
                        signallingClient.send(p0)
                        rtcClient.addIceCandidate(p0)
                        println("ice candidate to string: " + p0.toString()) // does not print
                    }

                    override fun onDataChannel(p0: DataChannel?) {
                        super.onDataChannel(p0)
                    }

                }
        )

        signallingClient = SignallingClient(createSignallingClientListener())

        call_button.setOnClickListener { // on-screen button to initiate sending the offer
            rtcClient.call(sdpObserver)
        }
    }
    
    private fun createSignallingClientListener() = object : SignallingClientListener {
        override fun onConnectionEstablished() {
            println("connection established")
        }

        override fun onOfferReceived(description: SessionDescription) {
            rtcClient.onRemoteSessionReceived(description)
            rtcClient.answer(sdpObserver)
            println("offer received") // prints
        }
        
        override fun onAnswerReceived(description: SessionDescription) {
            rtcClient.onRemoteSessionReceived(description)
            println("answer received") // prints
        }

        override fun onIceCandidateReceived(iceCandidate: IceCandidate) {
            rtcClient.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate)
            println("signalling client ice candidate") // does not print
        }
    }
```

**RTCClient.kt**

```kotlin
// imports omitted
class RTCClient(
        context: Application,
        observer: PeerConnection.Observer
) {

    init {
        initPeerConnectionFactory(context)
    }

    private val iceServer = listOf(
            PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302")
                    .createIceServer()
    )

    private val peerConnectionFactory by lazy { buildPeerConnectionFactory() }
    private val peerConnection by lazy { buildPeerConnection(observer) }

    private fun initPeerConnectionFactory(context: Application) {
        val options = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context)
                .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
                .createInitializationOptions()
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(options)
    }

    private fun buildPeerConnectionFactory(): PeerConnectionFactory {
        return PeerConnectionFactory
                .builder()
                .setOptions(PeerConnectionFactory.Options().apply {
                    disableEncryption = true
                    disableNetworkMonitor = true
                })
                .createPeerConnectionFactory()
    }

    private fun buildPeerConnection(observer: PeerConnection.Observer) = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(
            iceServer,
            observer
    )

    private fun PeerConnection.call(sdpObserver: SdpObserver) {
        val constraints = MediaConstraints().apply {
            //mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"))  // with this, the ICE candidate requests actually send, but I am not using audio so i do not think it needs to be here
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true")) // saw this constraint on an answer somewhere, I cannot tell if it is needed/or not
        }
        
        createOffer(object : SdpObserver by sdpObserver {
            override fun onCreateSuccess(desc: SessionDescription?) {

                setLocalDescription(object : SdpObserver {
                    override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
                    }

                    override fun onSetSuccess() {
                    }

                    override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {
                    }

                    override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
                    }
                }, desc)
                sdpObserver.onCreateSuccess(desc)
            }
        }, constraints)
    }

    private fun PeerConnection.answer(sdpObserver: SdpObserver) {
        val constraints = MediaConstraints().apply {
            //mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true")) // with this, the ICE candidate requests actually send, but I am not using audio so i do not think it needs to be here
            mandatory.add(MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"))
        }
        
        createAnswer(object : SdpObserver by sdpObserver {
            override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {
                setLocalDescription(object : SdpObserver {
                    override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
                    }

                    override fun onSetSuccess() {
                    }

                    override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {
                    }

                    override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
                    }
                }, p0)
                sdpObserver.onCreateSuccess(p0)
            }
        }, constraints)

    }

    private fun createChannel(label: String, peerConnection: PeerConnection?) {
        try {
            val init = DataChannel.Init().apply {
                negotiated = true
                id = 0
            }
            val channel = peerConnection?.createDataChannel(label, init)
            // here, channel is null

            val channelObserver: DataChannelObserver = DataChannelObserver()
            channel?.registerObserver(channelObserver)
            
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            println("creating channel exception: $e")
        }
    }

    fun call(sdpObserver: SdpObserver) = peerConnection?.call(sdpObserver)

    fun answer(sdpObserver: SdpObserver) = peerConnection?.answer(sdpObserver)

    fun createDataChannel(label: String) = this.createChannel(label, peerConnection)

    fun onRemoteSessionReceived(sessionDescription: SessionDescription) {
        peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(object : SdpObserver {
            override fun onSetFailure(p0: String?) {
            }

            override fun onSetSuccess() {
            }

            override fun onCreateSuccess(p0: SessionDescription?) {
            }

            override fun onCreateFailure(p0: String?) {
            }
        }, sessionDescription)
    }

    fun addIceCandidate(iceCandidate: IceCandidate?) {
        peerConnection?.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate)
    }
}
```

**SignallingClient.kt**

```kotlin
// imports omitted=
class SignallingClient(
    private val listener: SignallingClientListener
) : CoroutineScope {
    
    private val job = Job()

    private val gson = Gson()

    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO + job

    private val sendChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<String>()

    init {
        connect()
    }
    
    private fun connect() = launch {
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val request = Request.Builder().url("wss://random_ngrok_url").build() // here, I use ngrok since android has a problem with sending cleartext to a non-encrypted location. i also have the signalling server hosted on heroku, and it works the same

        val wsListener = CustomWebSocketListener(listener)

        val ws: WebSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, wsListener)
        
        listener.onConnectionEstablished()
        
        val sendData = sendChannel.openSubscription()
        
        try {
            while (true) {
                sendData.poll()?.let {
                    Log.v(this@SignallingClient.javaClass.simpleName, "Sending: $it")
                    println("signalling client send: $it")
                    ws.send(it)
                }
            }
        } catch (exception: Throwable) {
            Log.e("asd","asd",exception)
        }
        
        client.dispatcher.executorService.shutdown()
    }


    fun send(dataObject: Any?) = runBlocking {
        sendChannel.send(gson.toJson(dataObject, dataObject!!::class.java))
    }

    fun destroy() {
        job.complete()
    }
}
```

**CustomWebSocketListener.java** (forgive me for the java + kotlin mixup, I am more comfortable with java)

```java
// imports omitted
public class CustomWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

    private final SignallingClientListener listener;
    
    public CustomWebSocketListener(SignallingClientListener listener) {
        super();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
        super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull Throwable t, @Nullable Response response) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
        webSocket.close(1000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull String text) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
        JsonObject j = new Gson().fromJson(text, JsonObject.class);
        if (j.has("serverUrl")) {
            this.listener.onIceCandidateReceived(new Gson().fromJson(j, IceCandidate.class));
        } else if (j.has("type") && (j.get("type")).getAsString().equals("OFFER")) {
            this.listener.onOfferReceived(new Gson().fromJson(j, SessionDescription.class));
        } else if (j.has("type") && (j.get("type")).getAsString().equals("ANSWER")) {
            this.listener.onAnswerReceived(new Gson().fromJson(j, SessionDescription.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull ByteString bytes) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull Response response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
    }
}
```

**DataChannelObserver.java**

```java
// imports omitted
public class DataChannelObserver implements DataChannel.Observer {
    
    public DataChannelObserver(){}
    
    @Override
    public void onBufferedAmountChange(long l) {
        System.out.println("channel buffer amount changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChange() {
        System.out.println("channel state changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(DataChannel.Buffer buffer) {
        System.out.println("channel msg: " + buffer.toString());
    }
}
```

and finally, the signalling server

```js
'use strict';

const Uws = require('uWebSockets.js');
const uuid = require('uuid');

try {
    let listenSocket;
    
    let connectedClients = new Map();

    Uws.App({})
        .ws('/socket', {
            message: (ws, message, isBinary) => {
                const wsId = connectedClients.get(ws);
                for (const [socket, id] of connectedClients.entries()) {
                    if (socket !== ws && id !== wsId) {
                        console.log('sending message')
                        socket.send(message, isBinary);
                    }
                }
            },
            open: ws => {
                console.log('websocket opened');
                const wsId = uuid.v4();
                if (!connectedClients.has(ws)) {
                    connectedClients.set(ws, wsId);
                    console.log('added to connected clients: ' + wsId);
                } else {
                    console.log(wsId + ' already exists in connected clients')
                }
            },
        })
        .listen('0.0.0.0', Number.parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 9001, (token => {
            listenSocket = token;
            if (token) {
                console.log(`listening to port ${process.env.PORT || 9001}`);
            } else {
                console.log('failed to listen')
            }
        }))
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

(I believe that the signalling server works, as it just forwards the requests to the other, and currently I am just testing with two devices. I modeled it off the example signalling server)

The **SignallingClientListener** and **PeerConnectionObserver** classes can be found in the example linked above, I did not modify them.

I tried creating the data channel before creating the offer, after creating it, after the connection has been established, and it is always null. I use the negotiated connection since I just want something really basic, and will be able to agree on the ID beforehand.

I've not set up my own STUN/TURN servers as my devices worked with the video calling example and so I imagine they should work with this, but let me know if I'm wrong.

Any help or tips about other possibly easier solutions would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, I am testing on two android 10 devices, and the webrtc version is 1.0.32006.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, not entirely but will post what worked for me. Ultimately I could not figure out what was wrong with the code above, I suspect somewhere I was not doing something right with the initialization or requests.

Some of the files are from above and have not been modified, but I'll post them anyways. Also, I had used [this article](https://medium.com/@mehariaabhishek/how-to-use-webrtc-android-sdk-to-share-peer-to-peer-live-data-in-android-34b1aad1f1ba) as a starting point.

**CustomPeerConnection.java**

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import org.webrtc.DataChannel;
import org.webrtc.IceCandidate;
import org.webrtc.MediaConstraints;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory;
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;


public class CustomPeerConnection {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
    private PeerConnection peerConnection;
    private DataChannel dataChannel;
    private SignallingClient client;
    private CustomWebSocketListener wsListener;
    private Executor executor;
    
    public CustomPeerConnection(Context context, Executor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
        init(context);
    }
    
    private void init(Context context) {
        PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context)
                .createInitializationOptions();
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);
        PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
        PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder().setOptions(options).createPeerConnectionFactory();
        List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
        iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302").createIceServer());
        iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302").createIceServer());
        iceServers.add(PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("turn:numb.viagenie.ca").setUsername("").setPassword("").createIceServer()); // go create your own turn server for free
        PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);

        peerConnection = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, new CustomPeerConnectionObserver() {

            @Override
            public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
                super.onIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
                client.send(iceCandidate);
                peerConnection.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dc) {
                super.onDataChannel(dc);
                executor.execute(() -> {
                    dataChannel = dc;
                    dataChannel.registerObserver(new CustomDataChannelObserver());
                    sendMessage(dataChannel, "test");
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
                super.onIceConnectionChange(iceConnectionState);
                if(iceConnectionState != null){
                    if(iceConnectionState == PeerConnection.IceConnectionState.CONNECTED){
                        Log.d(TAG, "IceConnectionState is CONNECTED");
                    }
                    if(iceConnectionState == PeerConnection.IceConnectionState.CLOSED){
                        Log.d(TAG, "IceConnectionState is CLOSED");
                    }
                    if(iceConnectionState == PeerConnection.IceConnectionState.FAILED){
                        Log.d(TAG, "IceConnectionState is FAILED");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
                super.onSignalingChange(signalingState);
                Log.d("Signalling State", signalingState.name());
                if (signalingState.equals(PeerConnection.SignalingState.HAVE_REMOTE_OFFER)) {
                    createAnswer();
                } 
            }
        });

        DataChannel.Init dcInit = new DataChannel.Init();
        dataChannel = peerConnection.createDataChannel("dataChannel", dcInit);
        dataChannel.registerObserver(new CustomDataChannelObserver());
        
        this.wsListener = new CustomWebSocketListener(this);
        this.client = new SignallingClient(wsListener);
        
    }
    
    public void sendMessage(DataChannel dataChannel, String msg) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(msg.getBytes());
        boolean sent = dataChannel.send(new DataChannel.Buffer(buffer, false));
        Log.d("Message sent", "" + sent);
    }
    
    public void addIceCandidate(IceCandidate candidate) {
        this.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    }
    
    public void setRemoteDescription(CustomSdpObserver observer, SessionDescription sdp) {
        this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(observer, sdp);
    }

    public void createOffer(){
        MediaConstraints constraints = new MediaConstraints();
        constraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
        constraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("internalSctpDataChannels", "true"));
        constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "false"));
        constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "false"));
//        constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("IceRestart", "true"));
        
        peerConnection.createOffer(new CustomSdpObserver(){
            @Override
            public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                super.onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription);

                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new CustomSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
                client.send(sessionDescription);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
                super.onCreateFailure(s);
                Log.d(TAG, "offer creation failed: " + s);
            }
        }, constraints);
    }
    
    public void createAnswer() {
        MediaConstraints constraints = new MediaConstraints();
        constraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
        constraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("internalSctpDataChannels", "true"));
        constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "false"));
        constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "false"));
//        constraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("IceRestart", "true"));
        
        peerConnection.createAnswer(new CustomSdpObserver(){

            @Override
            public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                super.onCreateSuccess(sessionDescription);

                peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new CustomSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
                client.send(sessionDescription);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
                super.onCreateFailure(s);
                // Answer creation failed
                Log.d(TAG, "answer creation failed: " + s);
            }
        }, constraints);
    }

    public void close(){
        if(peerConnection == null){
            return;
        }

        if (dataChannel != null) {
            dataChannel.close();
        }
        peerConnection.close();
        peerConnection = null;
    }
    
    
}
```

**CustomDataChannelObserver.java**

```java
import android.util.Log;

import org.webrtc.DataChannel;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class CustomDataChannelObserver implements DataChannel.Observer {
    public CustomDataChannelObserver(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferedAmountChange(long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChange() {
        Log.d("Channel Observer", "State has changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(DataChannel.Buffer buffer) {
        ByteBuffer data = buffer.data;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[data.remaining()];
        data.get(bytes);
        final String message = new String(bytes);
        Log.d("Channel Observer", "msg: " + message);
    }
}
```

**CustomPeerConnectionObserver.java**

```java
import android.util.Log;

import org.webrtc.DataChannel;
import org.webrtc.IceCandidate;
import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection;
import org.webrtc.RtpReceiver;

public class CustomPeerConnectionObserver implements PeerConnection.Observer {
    public CustomPeerConnectionObserver(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] iceCandidates) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
        Log.d("CustomPeerConnectionObserver", dataChannel.label());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver rtpReceiver, MediaStream[] mediaStreams) {

    }
}
```

**CustomSdpObserver.java**

```java
import org.webrtc.SdpObserver;
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription;

public class CustomSdpObserver implements SdpObserver {

    public CustomSdpObserver(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSetSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateFailure(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSetFailure(String s) {

    }
}
```

**CustomWebSocketListener.java**

```java
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import org.webrtc.IceCandidate;
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription;

import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;
import okio.ByteString;

public class CustomWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
    
    public CustomPeerConnection peerConnection;
    
    public CustomWebSocketListener(CustomPeerConnection peerConnection) {
        this.peerConnection = peerConnection;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onClosed(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason);
//        System.out.println("Websocket closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
        super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason);
        webSocket.close(1000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull Throwable t, @Nullable Response response) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);
        System.out.println("websocket error: " + t.getMessage());
        webSocket.close(1000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull String text) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
        Log.d("socket listener", "received :" + text);
        JsonObject j = new Gson().fromJson(text, JsonObject.class);
//        Log.d("socket listener", "jsonobject keys: " + Arrays.deepToString(j.keySet().toArray()));
        if (j.has("serverUrl")) {
            peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new Gson().fromJson(j, IceCandidate.class));
        } else if (j.has("type") && (j.get("type")).getAsString().equals("OFFER")) {
            SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(
                    SessionDescription.Type.valueOf(j.get("type").getAsString()),
                    j.get("description").getAsString());
            
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new CustomSdpObserver(), sdp);
            
        } else if (j.has("type") && (j.get("type")).getAsString().equals("ANSWER")) {
            SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(
                    SessionDescription.Type.valueOf(j.get("type").getAsString()),
                    j.get("description").getAsString());
            
            peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new CustomSdpObserver(), sdp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull ByteString bytes) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket, bytes);
//        System.out.println("bytes msg: " + bytes.hex());
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull Response response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
//        System.out.println("Websocket opened");
        
    }
}
```

**SignallingClient.kt**

```kotlin
import android.util.Log
import com.google.gson.Gson
import io.ktor.util.KtorExperimentalAPI
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ConflatedBroadcastChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.WebSocket

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@KtorExperimentalAPI
class SignallingClient(
    private val socketListener: CustomWebSocketListener
) : CoroutineScope {
    
    private val job = Job()
    private val gson = Gson()
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO + job
    private val sendChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<String>()
    
    private val url: String = "" // set your socket url here
    
    private lateinit var ws: WebSocket
    private lateinit var client: OkHttpClient

    init {
        connect()
    }
    
    private fun connect() = launch {
        client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        ws = client.newWebSocket(request, socketListener)
        val sendData = sendChannel.openSubscription()
        try {
            while (true) {
                sendData.poll()?.let {
//                    Log.d(this@SignallingClient.javaClass.simpleName, "Sending: $it")
                    ws.send(it)
                }
            }
        } catch (exception: Throwable) {
            Log.e("asd","asd",exception)
        }
        
        client.dispatcher.executorService.shutdown()
    }


    fun send(dataObject: Any?) = runBlocking {
        sendChannel.send(gson.toJson(dataObject, dataObject!!::class.java))
    }

    fun destroy() {
        ws.close(1000, "destroy called");
        job.complete()
    }
}
```

**WebRtc2Activity.java**

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import com.project.R;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class WebRtc2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_rtc2);

        Executor g = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(getApplicationContext());
        CustomPeerConnection peerConnection = new CustomPeerConnection(getApplicationContext(), g);

        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(() -> peerConnection.createOffer(), 3000);
//        peerConnection.createOffer();
    }
    
}
```

**signalling server is the exact same as the one in the question.**

Truth be told, the above code is decent *starting code*, and needs improvements. The way it's run in the activity is not done well, and there really isn't any error handling or dropped connection checks. I only did so to be able to make sure the mechanism works. So to anyone who may find this useful, **do not run it the way I do here**, modify it or extend.

Answer (score 2):

```
private fun buildPeerConnectionFactory(): PeerConnectionFactory {
        return PeerConnectionFactory
                .builder()
                .setOptions(PeerConnectionFactory.Options().apply {
                    disableEncryption = true // This is the cause of your null DataChannel and null IceCandidates
                    disableNetworkMonitor = true
                })
                .createPeerConnectionFactory()
    }
```

I have just figure it out it in about 10 minutes before after been stuck for almost a month, now finally I can have some new progress for my trash project

Comment: you are the man

Comment: this is the one